# Find the extremal on the unit disc

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, polar-coordinates

I need help for finding the extremal of:
$$J[u]=\int\int_D (u_x^2+u_y^2) dxdy$$
$D$ is the unit disc i.e. $x^2+y^2 \leq 1.$
My boundary condition is
$$u(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)=\sin(n\theta), \ \ 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$

I have been using polar coordinates so far, please could you advise me how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting $(x,y)$ as the complex plane with $z= x+i y$. The Euler-Lagrange equation
$$ \Delta u =0$$
are solved by real and imaginary parts of holomorphic functions. Note that $f(z) = z^n$ is holomorphic in the unit disc and its imaginary part fulfills the boundary condition.

So the solution is $$u(x,y)= \text{Im} z^n = r^{n} \sin( n \theta)$$
with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\tan\theta= y/x$.

Comment: I'm not certain that this is the solution. I don't think of $(x,y)$ as the complex plane, but the real plane.

Comment: But maybe you should think of $(x,y)$ as the complex plane then as I have pointed out in my answer.